# Stanford CoreNLP: quote anotator

Tags: stanford-nlp

Per Stanford CoreNLP dependencies [page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html), the QuoteAnnotator has no depndencies. However, when I invoke the anotator in isolation, I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "quote" requires annotation "CorefChainAnnotation". The usual requirements for this annotator are: tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner

Is this expected behaviour? Do I run the full pipeline ahead?

Answer (score 1):

That documentation page is incorrect, I'll work on fixing it.  In the most recent version we've added quote attribution to the quote annotator by default.  This requires coreference.

If you don't want quote attribution you can set `-quote.attributeQuotes false`.

Alternatively you can just run this pipeline and get attributions for the quotes as well.

`-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,coref,quote`